# How can I make CMTime conform to Hashable on all iOS versions?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, ios16, swift-hashable

On Xcode 14, Apple added Hashable conformance to `CMTime` and `CMTimeRange` to iOS16 only. I'm trying to make it Hashable for all iOS versions, because we have many Hashable structs that contain `CMTime`, and they depend on `CMTime` to be Hashable as well.

Until now, we had an extension on `CMTime` that make it conform to Hashable, but on Xcode 14 this extension causes compilation error with this description:

```
Protocol 'Hashable' requires 'hashValue' to be available in iOS 14.0.0 and newer
```

If I implement `hashValue` like this:

```swift
  public var hashValue: Int {
    var hasher = Hasher()
    hash(into: &hasher)
    return hasher.finalize()
  }
```

It compile and works, but I'm not sure if it's safe because `hashValue` is deprecated so I'm not sure I understand why it's needed (only `hash(into:)` should be implemented for Hashable conformance these days).

Can anyone shed some light about whether this solution is safe, or have any other solution?

**Another idea that I tried:**

I added this extension on `CMTime`:

```swift
extension CMTime {
  struct Hashed: Hashable {
    private let time: CMTime

    init(time: CMTime) {
      self.time = time
    }

    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
      // pre iOS16 hash computation goes here.
    }
  }

  func asHashable() -> Hashed {
    return Hashed(time: self)
  }
}
```

Then I changed all Hashable structs that contain `CMTime` from this:

```swift
struct Foo: Hashable {
  let time: CMTime

  let string: String
}
```

to this:

```swift
struct Foo: Hashable {
  let time: CMTime

  let string: String

  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    if #available(iOS 16, *) {
      hasher.combine(self.time)
    } else {
      hasher.combine(self.time.asHashable())
    }
    hasher.combine(self.string)
  }
}
```

I'm not a fan of this since it will make a LOT of changes across the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2:**

The code below works with iOS 16 simulator, but crashes with iOS 15 and lower. Odd, since it compiles.

My suggestion is to implement an extension and make it available only for iOS 15 and lower:

```swift
@available(iOS, obsoleted: 16)
extension CMTime: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        var hasher = Hasher()
        hash(into: &hasher)
        return hasher.finalize()
    }

    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(value)
        hasher.combine(timescale)
        // more if needed
    }
}
```

As for why `hashValue` is still needed, I agree it's not suppose to be there. Might be an XCode false alarm, the error is really confusing.
Notice Apple doesn't say when it was deprecated, and also it was deprecated as a requirement, it's still there behind the scenes, I'm guessing: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable/hashvalue

**EDIT 1:**

`CMTime` already conforms to `Hashable`. Tested with iOS 13, 14, 15 and 16. I don't think you need your extension.

```swift
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

struct Foo: Hashable {
    let aaa: String
    let bbb: Int
    let time: CMTime
}

func testMyFoo() {
    let foo1 = Foo(
        aaa: "yo",
        bbb: 123,
        time: CMTime(
            value: 100,
            timescale: 1
        )
    )

    let foo2 = Foo(
        aaa: "yo",
        bbb: 123,
        time: CMTime(
            value: 100,
            timescale: 1
        )
    )

    var myFoos = Set<Foo>()
    myFoos.insert(foo1)
    myFoos.insert(foo2)

    print(myFoos)
    // you will only have 1 foo in the Set, because they are the same.
    // if you change the CMTime values in foo1, you will have 2 items in the Set.
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but even when I add the `available` marker, compilation fails with `Protocol 'Hashable' requires 'hashValue' to be available in iOS 14.0.0 and newer`, but requiring to implementing `hashValue` is surprising because it's deprecated.

Comment: @GuyNiv I've rewritten my answer. CMTime already conforms to Hashable. Am I missing something?

Comment: I appreciate your help :). I ran your code, and while it compiles, it crashes on the line `myFoos.insert(foo1)` with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Tested on iPhone 11 pro, iOS 15.0.

Comment: @GuyNiv NP. You're right about the crash. It works fine with iOS 16 simulator though, weird. I've updated my answer *EDIT 2*, I think you will need to implement the extension and obsolete it for iOS 16 (see code in EDIT 2)

Comment: Thanks everyone for this topic. I'm running into the same issue and getting a crash in release mode. I filed a bug [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/65063), feel free to provide any further details in there.

Comment: P.S. @GuyNiv did you manage to get around the crash? I figured a way with using `hashValue` directly, e.g., `[CMTime.zero.hashValue: "foo bar"]` – but this looks messed up… 

Comment: @IanBytchek Unfortunately @thedp answer didn't solve my problem, the implemented `hashValue` was never getting called, even for older iOS versions - so it made the app compile, but I had crashes in production because of this issue so this wasn't good for me. In the end I used the `Hashed` struct that is described in the original post. Your idea sounds similar to mine - messy but at least it works :)